# Cypress stub function gets lost after loading my app

Tags: reactjs, cypress

In my main React app's class `componentDidMount` I call an api method to fetch some data. I'm trying to test that my app does the right thing given the data. Rather than try and mock the server, and deal with Cypress's semi-support for `fetch` and whatnot, I'm trying to `cy.stub` the  entire API function to just return a block of data.

```
// api.ts

export const fetchData = async (): Promise<IData> => {
  ...
}
```

```
// app.tsx
import { fetchData } from "../api";

export class App extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {

  async componentDidMount() {
     const data = await fetchData(); 
     // ...
  }
}
```

```
// testData.test.ts

import * as Api from "../../src/api";

context("Test the app after loading mock data from the API", () => {

  describe("Calling the API",() => {

    before(() => {
      cy.stub(Api, "fetchData", () => {
        return Promise.resolve({
          someData: "value"
        });
      });

      cy.visit("/");
    });

    it("calls 'fetchData'", () => {
      expect(Api.fetchData).to.be.called;
    });

  });
});
```

However, the app still calls the original version of `fetchData` instead of the stubbed version.

I tried experimenting by writing a test that simply calls a library method that itself imports `fetchData`, and that time the mock worked fine. So mocking an ES6 function that way should work. So it's something to do with loading my application that causes it to get lost.

Comment: Hi Sam, I face the same problem as you, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with cy.visit. You can use the new plugin [@cypress/react](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/introduction) to do the trick ;)

Answer (score -1):

That's not really how the stubbing is supposed to work:

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Stubbing

> To begin stubbing responses you need to do two things.
>
> Start a cy.server()
> Provide a cy.route()

```
cy.server()           // enable response stubbing
cy.route({
  method: 'GET',      // Route all GET requests
  url: '/users/*',    // that have a URL that matches '/users/*'
  response: []        // and force the response to be: []
})
```

Not sure which API call you're trying to do, but this is a great headstart, and it doesn't require to have cypress any knowledge of your internal api work.

Not really knowing what you are trying to test, but a complete example would be this:

```
describe("Calling the API",() => {

    cy.server()           // enable response stubbing
    cy.route({
      method: 'GET',      // Route all GET requests
      url: '/users/*',    // that have a URL that matches '/users/*'
      response: []        // and force the response to be: []
    })
    .as('get-user')
    .visit('/')
    .wait('@get-user')    // wait for your call to finish and assert it has been called

})
```

Comment: I don't want to stub a network request. I'm looking to skip them entirely by stubbing a method instead. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/stub.html. By stubbing out my API method, I won't even try to make any network requests.

Comment: I realize that may be confusing from the method name being "fetch...". This should work the same if I were trying to sub out an async method called "performComplexCalaculation".

Comment: I get that, but I think with API requests you're better off with the network stubbing, because this kind of stubbing only works on instances, and in this case, you don't have an instance

Comment: if you can put the fetchData on an object, you might be able to stub it. Otherwise it might be placed on the window object? not sure where it lives

Comment: I have an experiment where I call "testLibrary" which itself imports "fetchData" exactly the same way (`import { fetchData } from "..."`), and in that case the stub worked perfectly. It's something to do with loading the app. The stub gets lost in the process.

Comment: I added an edit at the bottom of my post to clarify that.

Comment: @SamFen did you find any resolution for this ?

Comment: i am also looking for an answer to this and have asked about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69737283/stubbing-functions-on-cypress-io-being-ignored